# Entity Framework Video tutorials

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Are there any free video tutorials that talk about EF in depth and not just cover the basics?

Thanks

Comment: am about to start a project in EF4. This will lead to excellent information!

Answer (score 5):

It's not free, but I recommend the TekPub screencast:

http://tekpub.com/production/ef

Answer (score 5):

The video below is the greatest video that I have watched about Basics of Entity Framework 4.0. It is from Microsoft PDC event. Great speakers [Shyam Pather -Development Manager- and Chris Anderson -Developer], great demos. I strongly recommend you to watch it.

http://www.microsoftpdc.com/2009/FT10

Comment: This is a really good overview of the 'why' of EF. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/videos.aspx) are official EF & ADO.NET videos.

Answer (score 2):

There are several EF videos on [dotnetrocks](http://dotnetrocks.com/archives.aspx)